# How to control HTML Audio from ASP.NET page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I've added an HTML audio element and changed the source of audio on button click using C# code. Now I want to control the audio play/pause. How would I control the play/pause of this HTML audio element using ASP code?

HTML Audio element

```
<div runat="server" id="myDivTag">
    <audio autoplay runat="server" id="myaudio">
        <source src="" runat="server" type="audio/mpeg">
        <p>If you can read this, your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
    </audio>
</div>
```

ASP Code to control the audio

```
string ety ="http://audio.oxforddictionaries.com/en/mp3/ranker_gb_1_8.mp3";

 myaudio.Src = ety;
```

Comment: Which control you want to play or pause the audio? Something like changing button "play" to "pause" or vice versa, maybe?

Comment: I don't need a visible play/pause button, but some other buttons like maybe next/previous to play next song, when I click on the button it should replace the myaudio.Src and play again.

Comment: I think you need to use `addEventListener` DOM event to do that (with events `ended` and `click` to be handled for each "previous" & "next" button). The `click` event should add another song from other URL using `src` attribute then execute `load()` and `play()` methods.

Comment: Where is that audio tag from?